# Wordpress sub term slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I create a custom post type and a custom taxonomy.

```
<?php
function create_food_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'food_type',
        'foods',    
        array(  
            'label' => __( 'Categorieën' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'foods' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )   
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_food_tax' );
?>
```

If I create a new post the permalinks is www.mysite/food/the_post_title/
This permalink works fine but now...

On the page foods I created a loop for sub terms:

```
<?php
        $taxonomy = 'food_type';
        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
            'child_of'      => 450,
            'hide_empty'    => false,
        ) );
        foreach($terms as $term){ 
            echo get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy);
        }
?>
```

This loop show the links www.mysite/foods/soup/

If I click the link Wordpress give me a 404 error.
I flushed the permalinks but this does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

I already created a page in the WP-Backend with the same name as the slug from the custom taxonomy so I changed the name of the slug and flushed the permalinks.

Hope this information might help you out.

Comment: Hi Kalti, I changed a little in the code and now it turns to the homepage. Now I am looking for if the slug is equal get temp part :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the isssue. I created a taxonomy and created terms. I found in the documentation from Wordpress "create a file named" taxonomy-{yourtaxonomyname}-{your term}.php
[Wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/)